# Drop rows or update field on RANK() tie in Redshift / SQL

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, aggregate-functions

I have the following table:

IP Events:

```
customer_id   device_id device_type country_code      logical_event_timestamp              
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
customer1     dev1          dt1       US           2021-06-07 10:36:13.996000+00     
customer1     dev1          dt1       JP           2021-06-07 7:36:13.996000+00      
customer2     dev3          dt2       CA           2021-06-07 8:36:13.996000+00
customer1     dev1          dt1       JP           2021-06-08 12:36:13.996000+00
customer2     dev2          dt2       US           2021-06-08 14:36:13.996000+00
customer2     dev4          dt1       US           2021-06-08 16:36:13.996000+00
customer1     dev1          dt1       JP           2021-06-09 15:36:13.996000+00
customer1     dev2          dt2       US           2021-06-09 23:36:13.996000+00
customer2     dev3          dt2       US           2021-06-09 17:36:13.996000+00
```

And I want the following result (order doesn't matter):

```
customer_id  device_id  device_type  majority_country_code  last_event_timestamp
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
customer1      dev1        dt1           Tie         2021-06-09 15:36:13.996000+00
customer1      dev2        dt2           US          2021-06-09 23:36:13.996000+00
customer2      dev3        dt2           Tie         2021-06-09 17:36:13.996000+00
customer2      dev4        dt1           US          2021-06-08 16:36:13.996000+00
```

- Requirements:

  - For each day:

    - For each customer_id, device_id, device_type combination
      - Calculate the majority country for the day
      - If there is a tie for the day between two countries, don't count this day in the 30 day calculation
  - For the last 30 days (the table automatically deletes data older than 30 days):

    - For each customer_id, device_id, device_type combination

      - Calculate the majority country over the last 30 days
      - If there is a tie, set the majority_country_code field to 'Tie'

This is the SQL Query I have so far:

```
SELECT
    customer_id, device_serial_number, device_type, country_code, last_event_timestamp
FROM
    (SELECT
        customer_id, device_serial_number, device_type, country_code, COUNT(*
        ) AS cnt, MAX(last_event_timestamp
        ) AS last_event_timestamp, RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY customer_id, device_serial_number, device_type ORDER BY COUNT(*
            ) DESC
        ) AS rank 
    FROM
        (SELECT
            customer_id, device_serial_number, device_type, country_code, event_date, last_event_timestamp 
        FROM
            (SELECT
                customer_id, device_serial_number, device_type, country_code, COUNT(*
                ) AS cnt, DATE(logical_event_timestamp
                ) AS event_date, MAX(logical_event_timestamp
                ) AS last_event_timestamp, RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY customer_id, device_serial_number, device_type ORDER BY COUNT(*
                    ) DESC
                ) AS rank 
            FROM
                ip_address_events 
            GROUP
                BY customer_id, device_serial_number, device_type, country_code, event_date
            ) 
        WHERE
            rank = 1
        ) 
    GROUP
        BY customer_id, device_serial_number, device_type, country_code
    )
WHERE
    rank = 1;
```

This seems to work fine if there are no ties for a day or over the 30 days. How can I include the tie logic to drop the day's data if there is a tie in the daily aggregation and the tie logic to update the majority_country_code field to be 'Tie' if there is a tie in the aggregation over the last 30 days?

Summarized required logic:
Get the majority country (for a customer_id, device_serial_number, device_type combination) for 30 days based on the majority per day, but ignore days where there is no clear majority. If there is a tie over the 30 days, default the country to 'Tie'. Also, get the timestamp of the last entry for the customer_id, device_serial_number, device_type combination.

Comment: It would help if you summarized the logic you want.  It seems to be something like "Get the majority country for 30 days based on the majority per day -- but ignore days where there is no clear majority".  However, I'm not sure if that is correct.

Comment: Hi Gordan, you are mostly correct. I have updated the question to include the summarized required logic. Let me know if it is still not clear.